# Track Javascript on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to compare two pages and find out what went wrong https://web.archive.org/web/20141220055016/http://www.kenyabuzz.com/ and http://www.kenyabuzz.com/ on the archived version the dropdown on the top nav works. I don't know where the javascript is that `onhover` triggers on the `ul` how can I find it?

Comment: Why not using firebug or chrome development tools?

Comment: please see the console for errors which gives line number in script file
Press F12 in chrome to view developoer tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included jQuery 1.11 and it dropped support for things used in the version of fancybox that you are using. Look to see if there is a newer version of fancybox or see if the jQuery migrate plugin will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

on live version you are using new version of jquery which is breaking fancybox `TypeError: f.browser is undefined` because `browser` function is depreciated from jquery

You can fix it using [**jQuery Migrate**](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js) plugin